# How to get moodle's reports and other related data in python django rest

Tags: python, django, moodle

I want to work on a project in which i want to be able to access the reports and to create update and delete courses, assignments and quizzes in moodle via django api. But i don't know where to start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Moodle's web services.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services

Maybe start here. This explains how to create some PHP code

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client

Comment: I have created a webservice but i don't know how to access it in django. I tried to use this https://pypi.org/project/moodle-ws-client/ but it doesn't work either.